# How to include a folder of revision controlled binaries (dll) in a visual studios project in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs

I've joined a team where they have several Visual Studio solutions for different deliverables (managed by TFS). They have created an infrastructure where common 3rd party binaries are placed in a folder named `commonBin`.

They will add an appropriate `using` line in their `.cs` files and then add a reference to the `commonBin` directory.

The problem is... new code has references to new 3rd party libraries. So a solutions `.cs` files will have new `using` directives and references. However, when we do a `get latest` on the solution, it doesn't get the latest `commonBin` because it's not part of the solution.

Is there a way to resolve this? Other than doing a `get latest` on the whole baseline? I can see how to add a single item to the solution, so I could add just foo.dll or bar.dll, but I'd like to add the entire `commonBin` folder. (or maybe you have wisdom to share on why I would *not* want to do that).

Answer (score 1):

You should not store binaries in source control. Use a package manager like NuGet to handle versioning and resolution of binary dependencies.

Comment: Sadly we don't have that flexibility.

Comment: You do, you just don't want to. This is an engineering decision and the correct, best practice to solve the issue you have. Just fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the binary files to your Visual Studio solution (Add existing items in a new solution folder for example) even if the files are outside your solution folder.
When you do a 'get latest' at solution level it will update all items referenced.

This approach has some points where you have to be careful:

- If a library update requires new files (not only file changes) you have to remember to add the files to the solution or they will not be downloaded.
- Your solution folder will not contain all the files necessary to build, this complicate things when building in a server.

Definitely consider storing libraries somewhere else (Nuget server, file share...)